# Android: Queue Service invocations

Tags: java, android, service, android-service

I want to run Service called **SyncService** on different events like ***NetworkChange***, ***GpsChange***, ***AppOpenedByUser***, ***DeviceBoot***, ***OnNewSmsReceived***.

It has multiple network calls. If more than 1 event is happened at same time, or if 1 event is occured while the previous invocation was running, the service get invoked again. I want the invocation should happen only if the function is not running currently already. If it's already running, I want the service to wait for the previous execution to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you attempt to star service, Intent will be delivered to onStartCommandMethod. You can use 'Command' design pattern - create command from intent and add it in some command queue. After current command completes, you check is there is another commands in queue and execute another command. It it not, stop service. Notice, compared to IntentService, you should run it in background explicitly.